# NullPointerException creating generic type instance

Tags: java

Here is my Class

```
public class ManagerForm<M extends Stuff>{
private Class<M>clazz;
private M manager;

public void setWorker(M manager){
this.manager=manager;
}
public M getWorker(){
return this.manager;
}

private final Class<M> getGenericClass() {
        Class<M> persistentClass = null;
        Type genericType = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        if (genericType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType pType = ((ParameterizedType) genericType);
            // obtaining first generic type class
            persistentClass = (Class<M>) pType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }
        return persistentClass;
    }

public ManagerForm(){
this.clazz=getGenericClass();
this.manager=this.clazz.newInstance();
}
}
```

In default constructor in line `this.user=this.clazz.newInstance();` I have NullPointer exception `Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

Could anybody help me. What is going on? Why clazz creates null instance? Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

UPD

genericType belongs to Object type and is not instance of ParameterizedType. That's why function getGenericType returns null. Why?

When I use `Type genericType = getClass()` instead of `Type genericType = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();` I can get ManagerForm type. But ManagerForm doest belong to instance of ParameterizedType too?

Could anybody clear the situation?

Comment: Post the stacktrace; knowing which line the NPE was thrown from would narrow the cause down greatly ...

Comment: Should the calss declaration be
    public class ManagerForm<M extends Stuff>{

Comment: How are you making the object of ManagerForm?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.stuffmanager.classes.ManagerForm.<init>(ManagerForm.java:102)
 com.stuffmanager.controller.ManagerController.Manager(Manager.java:59)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)

Comment: ManagerForm.java:102 refers to line 102 in ManagerForm.java. What line is that in your listing? Also, note that you can edit your question to include clarification instead of posting them as comments. That would allow you to format them properly, and they are less likely to be missed by somebody too impatient to scan all these comments.

Comment: Never mind, there are only two lines in the constructor. Petar's answer is correct.

Comment: @Meriton ОК. 
I'm beginner for java. That's why I ask people who know java better than me. I need in default constructor to instantiate variable this.user of U type. Could anyone show me how to do this correctly?
 Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In your getGenericClass function:

```
genericType instanceof ParameterizedType
```

probably returns false, so persistentClass is null.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the if block within getGenericClass is not being executed. So the initial value of persistentClass is being returned. Having not run the code I could be wrong.